# How to prepare an asp.net app for xcopy deployment?`

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application that I currently deploy to 4 different environments on the client's servers.  At the moment we deploy by copying over individual assemblies and content files but the whole process is time consuming and error prone.  Basically I'd like a method of preparing the application for deployment that will give me a folder containing the application (no source code etc).  No IIS changes are required.  It would be good if I could specify different webconfigs for different environments.

I've looked at msbuild, msdeploy, etc and I'm not even sure which is the right tool for the job.  I'm tempted to go with a batch file that copies only certain file extensions but I'm sure there must be a better way of doing this.  Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Visual Studio [Publish Web Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) feature.

Comment: Thanks, ended up going for a combination of this and a batch file to do some bespoke tasks, works fine